# SSL connection could not be established error occurred in iOS simulator HTTPS localhost

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

While using HTTPS localhost in ios simulator (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception) exception occurred for proxy. While using HTTP localhost in ios simulator proxy working fine.How to resolve that exception using HTTPS localhost in ios simulator?

Comment: What does the inner exception show?  This is most likely due to using a self-signed certificate - there are many existing questions on how to deal with this

Comment: Inner exception shows :                                                                                                      Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: CertificateUnknown
at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.EvaluateTrust () [0x000bf] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.f…}

Comment: search on that error - there are many existing questions addressing this